# CSS behaving differently in IE 9 vs ie 10 or chrome

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9

So I was just looking into a issue at my client which is about a button turning orange at many places in IE9. I found out this CSS property
`progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ffff9900', endColorstr='#ffcc7a00', GradientType=0)` was causing the issue.

Does anybody have any idea what this is about and how to fix it.

Thanks

Comment: Take a look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532997(v=VS.85).aspx) and [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532887(v=VS.85).aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As **hungerstar** pointed, this is a Microsoft proprietary css property to create gradients using filters. If it's turning the button orange and you don't want it to be, you can simply remove it or even force the right color using '!important'

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532997(v=VS.85).aspx

Comment: its making it Orange in IE 9 in IE 10 and 11 it doesn't do anything.

Comment: That's because this filter is only supported until IE9, older IEs don't recognize this rule as valid. Try removing it from your css and see what happens :)